# How can I use toggle("slide") to show a phrase one letter at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a `.toggle("slide") function to try and get a piece of text I have to appear as if each letter is sliding in. Unfortunately, it looks as if the text is flying in instead. I tried to squeeze the margins in tight, so that it would start at a closer place, but it still looks as if it is flying in from the left side.

Is there a better way to do this, so it looks as if the letters are sliding in without "flying in"?

```js
$("#home-learn").toggle("slide");
```

```css
#blue {
 background-color: #0085A1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
}
#home-learn {
 color: #FFF;
 display: none;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 40%;
 top: 50%;
 font-size: 2.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blue">
  <div id="home-learn">Learn more...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the difference is between **sliding** and **flying**? What about it is wrong now? Is it too fast? Do you want each letter to slide in one at a time instead of all together? Its hard to tell what the problem is

Comment: I want the word, letter by letter, to slide in. No the word to come from the left side of the page and land in its specific location.

Comment: Maybet that is better for you like writen efect http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Customizable-Terminal-Text-Effect-TypeIt/

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am wanting the words to fadein, just in a slide approach. .

Comment: I don't see any effort in your code that would treat the text letter-by-letter

Comment: @Gavriel How don't you? I just want the text to fadeIn from the left to the right.

Comment: But your code already does that, the text fades in from left to right. But the whole text, not letter by letter, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the effect you want, put a div inside your container. Make the div position absolute, make it 100% the height and width of the container, and make it the same background color as the main background. Make the div's z index higher than the container so the div sits over the text like a curtain. Then use toggle() to slide the curtain to the right exposing the text underneath.

**Note** that this uses jQuery UI, without it, you can't make `toggle()` slide to the right like this needs.(at least to my knowledge you cant). If you dont want to use jquery UI, you could use `.animate()` instead of `toggle()`

```js
  $("#curtain-div").toggle("slide", {
    direction: "right"
  }, 3000);
```

```css
#blue {
  background-color: #0085A1;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

#home-learn {
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 2.3em;
}

#curtain-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #0085A1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="blue">
  <div id="home-learn">
    <div id="curtain-div"></div>
    Learn more...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for constructing this for me! It is more geared towards what I am looking for, but it still isn't it. Basically what I am looking for is the code to just slide in from the left to the right. Say `text-align: center;` was set, where that code appears, I don't want the words to show outside of that area. I want the starting point to fade in and then the rest after that.

Comment: @Paul Im sorry, I cant seem to grasp the look you are going for. COuld you explain it in a different way?

Comment: Ok. Image the code(text) is covered with a piece of paper. It is still and in place, Now, imagine you move the piece of paper to the right. The keeps the text in place, so it doesn't seem to "fly into place" and it slides over.

Comment: Hmm, ok I think I get it, just a min

Comment: @paul [Is this more like you wanted](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/2mpuj237/1/)?

Comment: Yes! exactly!...just not with an actual toggle button click event.

Comment: @Paul please see my update above, note that the margin you have given the container will make it act funny when the div  is narrow like in the snippet above so I removed it, add it back if needed

Comment: I can't get this to work in my application. I only see a tiny little line come in. I removed the margin I had and the display none, and added your new html and css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101499/discussion-between-paul-and-delightedd0d).

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: m.easing[this.easing] is not a functionZa.run @ jquery.js:6958i @ jquery.js:7342m.fx.timer @ jquery.js:7652kb @ jquery.js:7409g @ jquery.js:7499m.extend.dequeue @ jquery.js:4033g @ jquery.js:4014
1413jquery.js:6958 Uncaught TypeError: m.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Comment: @Paul, note the part where I said *Note that this uses jQuery UI,* ;)

Comment: I did not see that! To be honest, I only used it for one other thing before, so I don't really know much about it. That made it work. Thanks!!!